# Is there a way to programmatically create copies of a layout in android?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

The main goal is to use a pre-made layout to create separate modules that can be edited, and then programmatically add them to the root layout. To clarify, [several modules stuck together would look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA28s.png) I would like to dynamically create each clickable block that consists of a name, date, and letter. The .axml code for each block is as follows:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/borderLayout"
            android:background="@drawable/line"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#ff2f2f2f">
                <TextView
                    android:text="C"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Washington"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="right" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="6-8-17"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The main problem I am having is formatting the views programmatically in the same way that I formatted them in the .axml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you have a `LinearLayout` with an orientation of `vertical` in your main axml that you wish to attach multiple views to.

Get a reference to that "parent" `LinearLayout`:

```
var linearLayoutParent = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
```

Then in some loop, use `LayoutInflater.Inflate` to inflate your repeating layout, use the view returned and `FindViewById` on that `View` each of the elements you need to update and then add that view to the parent view with an increasing index:

```
index++;
var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RepeatingLayout, linearLayoutParent, false);
var letter = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
letter.Text = index.ToString();
// FindViewById for textView2, textView3 and assign the text on each....
linearLayoutParent.AddView(view, index);
```

[image]

Note: If you have a lot of these repeating elements and you will have to scroll them (off screen), look at using a `RecyclerView` instead, it will save you a lot of headaches into terms of memory management, scrolling performance, etc... ;-)

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Use inflater to create a view from resource. Then you can add it programmatically

```
context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.oneimg_twolbl, null);
```