# Xamarin dynamically added views using inflater inside loop adding only one entry

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, duplicates

I followed the below link to dynamically add a layout multiple times using inflater and AddView()

[Is there a way to programmatically create copies of a layout in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420870/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-create-copies-of-a-layout-in-android)

I used a loop to create multiple entries. But only one entry is comming up which is the result of last loop index

Below is my C# code

I can see only one child inside the parent which is the result of last loop.
What I missed?

```
var parent = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.ParentLayoutWrapper);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RepeatingLayout, parent, false);
                            var txtView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewSample);
                            txtView.Text = i.ToString()+ " Android application is debugging";
                            txtView.Id = i;
                            parent.AddView(view, i);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original post you worked from had a [LinearLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/linear-layout) as the parent layout, not a [RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout) like you have. When you add a view (or another layout) to a `LinearLayout`, it gets positioned below (when `LinearLayout` has vertical orientation) any existing elements in the layout. However, the elements in a `RelativeLayout` need to use positioning properties to determine where they will be in the `RelativeLayout`, so every time you add the new layout, `RepeatingLayout`, since you are not changing the layout options, the view/layout is added over the existing view/layout. So change the parent layout to a `LinearLayout` in your layout file and then this should work:

```
LinearLayout parent = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.parentLayout);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RepeatingLayout, null);
    var tv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewSample);
    tv.Text = i.ToString() + " Android application is debugging";
    parent.AddView(view);
}
```

Trying to do the same with a `RelativeLayout` as the parent layout highly complicates things unnecessarily.